# Catching ThreadingException in VB.NET when Sub Main is not accessible

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

I have a VB.NET winforms solution, and would like to add the standard application exception handlers - `Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.

I have the following code [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)

```
' Starts the application. '
<SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags:=SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlAppDomain)> _
Public Shared Sub Main()
    ' Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event. '
    AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf ErrorHandlerForm.Form1_UIThreadException

    ' Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through'
    ' our handler. '
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)

    ' Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. '
    AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf CurrentDomain_UnhandledException

    ' Runs the application. '
    Application.Run(New ErrorHandlerForm())
End Sub
```

How can I do it in VB.NET when I have no acces to the `Sub Main()` method?

Is the case when "Enable Application Framework" of my solution properties is enabled (`Sub Main` is hidden)...

Comment: Copy the first three lines of code into the first method call which you _do_ have access to. There's going to be a small window for contingency here, but you win some, you lose some.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: see the same comment as to RoadWarrior bellow...

Answer (score 2):

You can intercept the [My.Application.Startup event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4zch4d2%28VS.80%29.aspx) to add code that needs to run before any forms are loaded.

Note that the code for the Startup event handler is stored in the ApplicationEvents.vb file, which is hidden by default.

EDIT: To answer your comment, there's a confusion between My.Application and System.Windows.Forms.Application. If you prefix .Application with System.Windows.Forms, it will work - I've just tested this.

Comment: `Application.ThreadException` does not exists in that context.

Comment: meybe for unhandled there is need to Handle me.UnhandledException... but not sure if it do for the ThreadException too...

Comment: maybe for unhandled there is need to Handle me.UnhandledException... but not sure if it do for the ThreadException too...

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem, I think - it seems you are missing an `Imports` statement at the head of your code file. You can either add the required `Import` or fully qualify the types you're accessing:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Shared Sub MyApplicationInitialization()
    AddHandler System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException, AddressOf MyThreadExceptionHandler

    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)

    AddHandler System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyUnhandledExceptionHandler
End Sub
```

As you can see from this, `AppDomain` lives within the `System` namespace and `Application` within the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

Notice that you will also need to define your own event handling methods to be specified after each `AddressOf`. These can be laid out as follows:

```
Sub MyUnhandledExceptionHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    'your logic here
End Sub

Sub MyThreadExceptionHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
    'your logic here
End Sub
```

Comment: there is no need to use imports if you use the explicit namespaces. that really simple and worked. from the other part, maybe even I don't need that, because there is a possibility in the ApplicationEvents.vb to do `Private Sub Application_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException` but I am not sure if it does also for the threadExceptions too, or just for Unhandled ones...

Comment: Ya, the first line explains that there are two options, fully qualify the type name or use an import. As for your handlers, where they are defined is irrelevant in terms of functionality, so long as they're appropriately accessible.

Comment: I thought that one thing is to use `AddHandler System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, and an other one is to use `Handles Me.UnhandledException`, because `Me` and `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain` are different things, i believe, also, you answer does nto reveal, where exactly your sub should be used...

Comment: My `Subs` should be _used_ by delegating execution to them using `AddHandler` as exemplified in the code snippet. the way _you_ use them to handle exception is completely up to you. As for using `Me.UnhandledException`, these ought to equate to the same thing - where exceptions bubble up to and passed this point, up to the Application level.